# Correct usage of Him and Himself

Tags: pronouns, reflexive-pronouns

In following piece of text, why author used **him** instead of **himself**?

In the 1500s, the Spanish explorer Cortes met the Aztecs. Cortes became quiet interested in plantations where the Aztecs cultivated chocolate trees. When he returned to Europe, he took cacao beans with **`him`**. He introduced the people of Spain to the Aztecs' chocolate beverage.

*Reference*: *4000 Essential English words, Paul Nation, Book 4*

---

According to [here](http://www.grammar.cl/Notes/Reflexive_Pronouns.htm) we not use reflexive pronoun:

> After a preposition of place or location we use a personal pronoun and
>   not a reflexive pronoun.

Is this true for the above situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is true for the situation you've cited.

> he took cacao beans with him

is correct.

> he took cacao beans with **himself**

does not really mean anything, the closest might be

> he took cacao beans **himself**

which would mean he *brought* cacao beans, whereas others did not.